# Java : Is it possible to return an array of Objects from one class to another

Tags: java

I have a class named **MyVisitor** that extends another class named **Value**. In one of my methods in **MyVisitor**, I have to store an array of Values in a HashMap. However, since the **MyVisitor** only extends **Value**, I can't return **Value[ ]** in the HashMap. Due to my limited knowledge on Java this is the solution I found:

In my **Value** class, I have:

```
public static int x;
public static Value ARRAY = new Value(new Object[x]); // I assume this would return an array of Objects of size x?

public Object[] objArray(){
   return (Object[])value;
}
```

In MyVisitor class, I have this HashMap:

```
public Map<String, Value> array_memory = new HashMap<String, Value>();
```

In MyVisitor class, I have a method named **array** that uses Value.ARRAY like so:

```
Value.x = x; //Would change the value of public static int x in class Value
return array_memory.put(id, Value.ARRAY);
```

I have another method named **arrayDec** that calls **array** and does the following:

```
array(ctx);
String key = ctx.ID().getText();
Object[] val = array_memory.get(key).objArray();
System.out.println(val.length);
```

val.length prints 0

I have the following question:

1. Does `= new Value(new Object[Value.x]);` actually create an array of Objects of size x and masks it as Value?
2. Also, does Value.ARRAY actually return an array of Objects of size x?
3. Why does val.length return 0?

Confused? yeah me too :(

Also, if you're wondering why I'm doing this, I have a project in one of my courses that requires us to create our own compiler/interpreter. I'm trying to implement arrays. I'm using antlr4 to help me with it (thus the ctx.ID().getText() in one of the snippets there)

Any help would be appreciated. And if you have a better idea of how I should implement this I'm open to suggestions. Or if you know any links about implementing arrays in antlr4 that would be awesome as well. Thanks!

Comment: It is clearly possible to return an array of `Object`.  Can you reduce your question to a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. It creates an instance of Value. This instance might hold an array of Object if you have defined a constructor that takes an Object array as a parameter and assign that parameter to a member.
2. No. It returns an instance of Value
3. Impossible to say. Your code doesn’t explain how the member ‘value’ is defined or assigned.

Comment: would something like this be okay? 

          `public static Value ARRAY = new Value(new Object[x]);

          Object[] array = new Object[x];

          public Value(Object[] array){
                 this.array = array;
          }`

Comment: The constructor, yes. You don’t need to initialize ‘array’ if it gets assigned in the constructor.

Comment: I see, if you don't mind I have another question : could I access the array of Objects inside the instance using `val.array[0]` given that val is of type Value?

Comment: Yes you can access the ‘array’ member that way but if you want the whole array you should write ‘val.array’ because ‘val.array[0]’ will only give you the first object in the array.

Comment: I see, thank you very much, you have been very helpful. just one more question, even though I've changed the value of x inside the class Value like so: `Value.x = x` I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Shouldn't the array of Objects be of size x given that `public static Value ARRAY = new Value(new Object[x]);` ?

Comment: The use of a static Value object is confusing to me and maybe it would be best for your design if you got rid of it. Anyway, as I see it when the ARRAY value is created x is 0 and this will be the size of ARRAY.array even if you change x later on.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Kudos to you sir!